# How do you show one way equivalences in mathematics?

Tags: logic, relations, order-theory, equivalence-relations, causality

In the real world, it seems you can often take a set of things and create new things with them. Let's say you want to make bread, for example. Normally, you can create bread by putting together flour, milk, eggs, and a few other ingredients, and cooking.

It would seem, that this could be written as:

> $flour+milk+eggs+(other ingredients)=bread$

I believe there is a problem with this though, in that you can't create milk or flour (in any practical way) from bread. It just wouldn't work.

So, in specific to that problem, I'm wondering of there is a way to identify one way equivalences in mathematics. That is $x$ and $y$, such that $x$ can turn into $y$, but $y$ cannot turn into $x$. I guess that can lead to the more complicated issue of causation, which I'm also wondering about.

Comment: Here's a [relevant (series of) post(s)](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/resource-convertibility-part-1/) on John Baez's blog. It's eerily similar, but pretty high in abstraction and terminology, at points.

Comment: Sorry but the sentence "such that $x=y$, but $y$ does not equal $x$" isn't really meaningful. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Ive edited it to clarify @YvesDaoust . Hopefully that didn't change the question to much

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: I did give an example. With the bread. Milk and eggs and stuff are X, and bread is y.

Comment: @samarbarrett: be serious, you didn't explain at all your meaning.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for. Roughly speaking, let a function $f$ be the 'cooking' operator which takes a set of ingredients to the thing you can make with it. For example, $f( {flour,milk,eggs,etc} )=bread$. Clearly, from this, one cannot 'subtract $milk$ from both sides'. Also since $f$ need not be invertible, there is no way mathematically to turn $bread$ directly back into the ingredients.

Comment: You might find some useful information by reading about how to apply linear logic to model utilization of resources (I am thinking about the way implications are conceived in linear logic). Unfortunately, I am not a logician, therefore this hint is the best that I can do for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to expand upon my comment because this is a very interesting question.

---

First, I think the word "causation" is really throwing people off. Causation *does* have a specific meaning that's been modeled in various ways (I'm thinking statistics and mathematical logic), but none of the ways I know about capture what (I think) you're after.

The [link](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/resource-convertibility-part-1/) I posted in my comment is to a post about "Resource Convertibility," which really perfectly captures what you've been thinking about, or at least the example you gave. I don't know much about it, but it's fun to think about, so I'll try to say a little bit.

---

You've got a very interesting idea that surprisingly intersects with some current research!

Unfortunately, it may turn out that *equality* has connotations that are inappropriate, as you've already seen:

> $$\rm flour\ + milk\ +eggs\ + (other\ ingredients) = bread$$

is indeed something of an unfortunate notation, because equality is *symmetric* and as you've pointed out, our conversion here is really one way.

Tobias Fritz has evidently been thinking about this, and decided that an *inequality* was really the way to go: It makes more sense to write

$$\rm flour\ + milk\ +eggs\ + (other\ ingredients) \ge bread$$

and think of this statement as something like "having flour, milk, eggs, and other stuff is *at least as good* as having bread" (highly paraphrased from link above). It's also probably best to avoid *causation* and speak strictly about the ability to *convert* the things on the left to the things on the right (as the act of bringing milk and eggs together certainly doesn't *cause* bread to form of its own volition!).

The key features of his formulation are that

- You have some means of "comparing" objects, using $\ge$.

  - Everything is comparable to itself (i.e., $\rm bread \ge bread$).
  - Comparisons are *transitive*. For example if $\rm bread\ ingredients \ge bread$, and $\rm bread \ge toast$, then $\rm bread\ ingredients \ge toast$ (just bake the ingredients into bread, then slice and toast!).
  - Finally, antisymmetry (think $x \ge 3$ and $3 \ge x$ means $x = 3$) is used as a means to decide what resources are equivalent. We have, for example (by visiting one's favorite financial institution and trading cash for different cash),

$$\rm five\ \$1\ bills \ge one\ $5\ bill \qquad and \qquad one\ $5\ bill \ge five\ \$1\ bills.$$

- We also have the ability to add objects, as in the $\rm flour + milk + \ldots$ example (but the $+$ really just lets us build a shopping cart from what I can tell; adding doesn't convert anything, that's all encapsulated in $\ge$).

With these abilities, you get to say you're studying fancy things called ordered commutative monoids, and you can read much much more in the series of posts linked above, as well as [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03661) that ensued (there's a lot of fancy notation and theorems, but there's some value to skimming at least portions of the paper, if you find the blog series interesting enough).

---

Has any of this turned out to be useful, from a practical standpoint? I have no idea! But John Baez (the person running the blog) as been involved in, and popularized, efforts to build a framework to talk and think about network theory: Chemical reactions (think $H + O \ge H_2O$), birth-death processes, resource conversion, etc. It turns out that classical mathematics can only say so much about these subjects.

This perspective on Resource Convertibility is just one of many efforts to find a good framework.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer

Comment: You're quite welcome, and thank you! I personally like the question, I'm sorry it's gaining you some flak and a few close votes. It's hard stuff to grapple with, I'm sympathetic to having a hard time phrasing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best mathematical setting to represent physical causation are [dynamical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system_(definition)):

- You have a global "state" $x(t)$ (a vector with many coordinates) with flour, milk and eggs represented by set of variables changing in the time variabe $t$,
- you have physical laws represented by a rule linking $x(t)$ to $x(t+dt)$ (maybe a differential equation),
- you have a a "macro"-state $X(t)$ that is represented by a set of "micro"-state $x(t)$ that we identify (for example there are several micro-state that we would call "bread" and several micro-states that we would call "unmixed flour, milk and eggs"),
- you have causation if the macro-state $A$ (in any given possible micro-state configuration) always evolves to the macro-state $B$ (in some micro-state configuration), then you would say that "$A$ causes $B$".

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in causality, then the book "Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference" by Judea Pearl should be of interest to you. It's a little difficult to judge from your question what you are actually after, but my guess is you will find plenty of illumination in that book.

Answer (score -1):

I think the mathematical concept you want is *implication*.

For example, think about mathematical equations that only work sometimes. How about $x^2=x$. If you plug in a random value of $x$, that equation isn't true. But it happens to work when $x=1$. Written mathematically,

$$ x = 1 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x^2 = x$$

The symbol $\Longrightarrow$ is read as *implies*, or as the *then* part of an if-then statement. You can also think about it as meaning mathematical causation -- e.g. the fact that $x=1$ causes the equation $x^2=x$ to be true. This arrow doesn't always go both ways. If it's true that $x^2=x$, that doesn't imply that $x=1$. (It could instead be true that $x=0$.)

Warning: there are some problems with this perspective, namely that in mathematical logic, any false statement implies any statement you want. This is worth thinking about some more!

Comment: I actually disagree with this - conflating mathematical implication with cause-and-effect can lead to confusion (see any of the threads on this site about how a false statement can imply a true statement!).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I actually disagree with it too. I had thought of my post as "getting your feet wet with the concepts", but your comment made me realize I needed at least a caveat. Thanks!

Comment: @NoahSchweber: In fact, this answer is even better than its author even imagined - provided that you agree to change your view about what "implication" means. Girard's linear logic has some very interesting things to say about this - alas I am not a logician so I can't further detail this comment.